# Instantiating a .Net object that has a VB6 defined COM interface in .Net throws TypeLoadException

Tags: c#, .net, vb6, com-interop

I have a COM interface defined in a VB6 COM DLL called `IODevice`.

```
Public Sub Connect(ByVal Device As String)
End Sub

Public Sub Disconnect()
End Sub
```

I have a .Net class that imports and implements this interface.

```
[ComVisible(true)]
[Guid("92255E76-6C1A-333F-883C-6EE9FD9937BA")]
public class COMInterface : ICIO.IODevice {
    public COMInterface() {
        // Do nothing
    }

    public void Connect(string deviceString) {
        // Do stuff
    }

    public void Disconnect() {
        // Undo stuff
    }
}
```

This object works well, and can by created in VB6 using `CreateObject()` and referenced as the `IODevice` interface.

I am now moving the calling code to .Net and using `Activator.CreateInstance`.

```
Type deviceType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID(typeProgID, true);
object instance = Activator.CreateInstance(deviceType);
```

Again, this code works fine and will instantiate and use any of the VB6 classes that implement `IODevice`. The problem comes when I try and load the .Net objects that implement that interface.

```
System.TypeLoadException: Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {92255E76-6C1A-333F-883C-6EE9FD9937BA} failed due to the following error: 80131522. 
   at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandle& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck) 
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean fillCache) 
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceImpl(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipVisibilityChecks, Boolean fillCache) 
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic) 
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type) 
   at iCode.Console.IOEngine.Wrappers.ICIO.IODeviceWrapper.ConnectDevice()
```

If I remove the interface from `COMInterface` then the object can be instantiated fine, but lacks the interface allowing me to use any of its members.

```
public class COMInterface /*: ICIO.IODevice*/ {
```

All libraries are set to target `x86` and .Net 2, but changing these as no affect on the outcome.
I've also confirmed that the VB6 library hosting the `IODevice` interface and its interop DLL are in the same folder as the assembly containing `COMInterface`.

What am I missing, what is it failing to do and how can I create an instance of this object from .Net while keeping the `IODevice` interface?

(The example code is stripped out of a large code base, but I'll try and create a minimal example.)

Comment: It is really rather a bad idea to have .NET code use COM to load a .NET type.  If forcing the debugger to stop on the first-chance exception does not help then at least temporarily add a reference to the assembly so you can debug the problem.  Consider keeping it that way :)

Comment: I'm aware it's a bad idea, but it's sadly what I have to work with. The original VB6 code handled any number of objects (by ProgID), and there is a large range of libraries that implement this original interface (from ~15 years ago), both in VB6 and .Net. The time I try and get rid of some of the VB6, it falls in a heap :)

Comment: It has given me the idea though of detecting it's a .Net based object and load it via using .Net methods

Answer (score 2):

This is caused by the runtime being unable to resolve type used by the original `IODevice` interface (in this case, `VBA.vbVarType`).

When I tried to load the assembly and get the type directly with reflection, I received this exception:

```
System.TypeLoadException: Method 'get_PortType' in type 'NetLibrary.COMInterface' does not have an implementation.
   at System.Reflection.Assembly._GetType(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase)
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.GetType(String name)
   at InstantiationTest.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

Adding a COM reference to `msvbvm60.dll` allowed this type to be loaded directly, and in turn, the original code was able to create an instance of the object.